# Cakephp model association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I am trying to figure out which relationship type should I use to relate the following:

We have a classroom that has a teacher and students.

Students and teacher belongsTo classroom. But what about the other way around?

Can I use the following in the Classroom model:

`var $hasMany = array('Students');`

`var $hasOne = array('Teacher');`

Thanks.

Comment: it depends on what operation constraints you want to have on these models. In real life, a student can have many teachers; but if a student can only have 1 teacher in your app, then hasOne is the right relationship.

Comment: well, in my case, the classroom is more of an administrative thing, where I can access a classroom and see its students and teacher. A classroom can have multiple students and one teacher. A student can only belong to one classroom. A teacher is in charge of a classroom and should have the ability to list the students in the classroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to retrieve and/or model the data.

Assuming your `Classrooms` will only have one `Teacher`, or `Teachers` will only have one `Classroom`, you can even get away with making `Classroom` a field of `Teacher`.

But we'll assume you want to keep it all abstracted from each other. In this case, your models would look something like this:

```
// classroom.php
class Classroom extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array( 'Student' );
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 'Teacher' );
}

// teacher.php
class Teacher extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array( 'Student' );
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array( 'Classroom' );
}

// student.php
class Student extends AppModel {
    var $belongsTo = array( 'Teacher', 'Classroom' );
}
```

Comment: could you explain a bit the $hasAndBelongsTo in the teacher model. What would be the difference with a $belongsTo ?? Thanks!

Comment: When you're thinking of these relationships, remember that they exist to allow for easy joining of models.What $hasAndBelongsToMany allows is for *cross-joining* and joining in more complex ways. Say you have a blog with users who post and users who respond in comments. A user can be part of a post, be part of a comment (if, say, you had username tagging), "own" a post and "own" comments. A simple $hasMany, or $belongsTo relationship doesn't well handle the bidirectional nature of these relationships. I recommend reading through this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Answer (score 0):

Its very dependent on your situation but at my old school that would indeed be correct though maybe an unnecessary relationship to add.

Teacher has many students
Classroom has one teacher
Classroom has many students

However, do the students move around? Is the relationship between students and classroom entirely necessary? I would think the most defining relationship in this instance is the teacher-student one. Then perhaps the teacher-classroom. You can surmise based on those relationships that some students are part of a classroom.

Therefore:

Classroom - Teacher -< Students
Classroom (has one) Teacher (has many) Students

You would then find the students of a classroom via the Teacher.